# Part2: How to remove all unwanted TreeView Branches. self-join table

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, self-join

Part1: In a C# Treeview, I need to remove all branches that do not contain values in a list in the leafs.
For example, I have a list { 10, 13 }  and a Tree:
The Data Source is a self-joined table. So I can't easily remove the unwanted leafs and branches.

--> Best Answer
        void TrimTree(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List l)
        {
            TreeNode node = null;
            for (int ndx = nodes.Count; ndx > 0; ndx--)
            {
                node = nodes[ndx - 1];
                TrimTree(node.ChildNodes, l);
                if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 0 && !l.Contains(node.Value))
                    nodes.Remove(node);
            }
        }

If I can write a better SELECT query, then I won't need the TrimTree() function :D
Solving this will help a LOT!  Thank you so much!

Part2:
Others have pointed out simply modifying the UI is just a work around.
So how can I change the SELECT query so all the unwanted branches and leafs never get in the tree in the first place.

Currently I just do this (it works):
DataTable dt = GetTable("select id, parent_id, name from tbl_self_join"); 
tvTree.DataSource = HierarchicalDataSet(dt, "id", parent_id");
tvTree.DataBind();

Here is a simple self-join table example:

ID      Partent_ID       Name

```
1   null   Root
2   1   Branch1
9   2   Branch1-Sub1
10  2   Branch1-Sub2
11  2   Branch1-Sub3
12  11  Branch1-Sub3-Sub1
13  11  Branch1-Sub3-Sub2
14  1   Branch2
15  14  Branch2-Sub1
18  14  Branch2-Sub2
19  18  Branch2-Sub2-Sub1
20  19  Branch2-Sub2-Sub1-sub1
```

So If I want to remove all leafs except the ones with ID 10,13, I should get this:

ID Parent_ID  Name

1   null    Root

2   1   Branch1

10  2   Branch1-Sub2

11  2   Branch1-Sub3

13  11  Branch1-Sub3-Sub2

If I simply remove the leafs I don't want, the branches will remain. 
Is there a a SELECT statement that can do this? 
Then a work-a-round isn't needed.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No comments?  Maybe this is very difficult?